# ESP32 stops sending data via wifi after a while

Tags: c++, esp32

I am using an esp32 to send some environmental data, such as temperature, humidity, pressure, pm2.5, and TVOV to a thinkspeak server. This works sometimes for a few hours and then it suddenly stops sending data. It also seems to be a bit random on when it stops. Sometimes it works just a few minutes and sometimes much longer. My code is probably is a great mess as I combined the codes from different sensors. Can anybody check the code and maybe see what my ESP32 suddenly stops sending data?

Code:

```
#include <WiFi.h> 
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_SGP30.h"
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>
#define LENG 31   //0x42 + 31 bytes equal to 32 bytes

unsigned char buf[LENG];

Adafruit_SGP30 sgp;

int PM01Value=0;          //define PM1.0 value of the air detector module
int PM2_5Value=0;         //define PM2.5 value of the air detector module
int PM10Value=0;         //define PM10 value of the air detector module
float h, t, p, pin, dp;
char temperatureFString[6];
char dpString[6];
char humidityString[6];
char pressureString[7];
char pressureInchString[6];

/* return absolute humidity [mg/m^3] with approximation formula
* @param temperature [°C]
* @param humidity [%RH]
*/
uint32_t getAbsoluteHumidity(float t, float h) {
   //approximation formula from Sensirion SGP30 Driver Integration chapter 3.15
   const float absoluteHumidity = 216.7f * ((h / 100.0f) * 6.112f * exp((17.62f * t) / (243.12f + t)) / (273.15f + t)); // [g/m^3]
   const uint32_t absoluteHumidityScaled = static_cast<uint32_t>(1000.0f * absoluteHumidity); // [mg/m^3]
   return absoluteHumidityScaled;
}

char checkValue(unsigned char *thebuf, char leng)
{  
  char receiveflag=0;
  int receiveSum=0;
 
  for(int i=0; i<(leng-2); i++){
  receiveSum=receiveSum+thebuf[i];
  }
  receiveSum=receiveSum + 0x42;
 
  if(receiveSum == ((thebuf[leng-2]<<8)+thebuf[leng-1]))  //check the serial data 
  {
    receiveSum = 0;
    receiveflag = 1;
  }
  return receiveflag;
}
int transmitPM01(unsigned char *thebuf)
{
  int PM01Val;
  PM01Val=((thebuf[3]<<8) + thebuf[4]); //count PM1.0 value of the air detector module
  return PM01Val;
}
//transmit PM Value to PC
int transmitPM2_5(unsigned char *thebuf)
{
  int PM2_5Val;
  PM2_5Val=((thebuf[5]<<8) + thebuf[6]);//count PM2.5 value of the air detector module
  return PM2_5Val;
  }
//transmit PM Value to PC
int transmitPM10(unsigned char *thebuf)
{
  int PM10Val;
  PM10Val=((thebuf[7]<<8) + thebuf[8]); //count PM10 value of the air detector module  
  return PM10Val;
}

String apiKey = "6HNZHJJA9KD2PM43";
// replace with your routers SSID
const char* ssid     = "XXX";
const char* password = "XXX";

const char* server = "api.thingspeak.com";
WiFiClient client;

Adafruit_BME280 bme; // I2C

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  
    // Printing the ESP IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  

 if (!bme.begin(0x76)) 
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1); 
  }

  if (! sgp.begin()){
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid SGP30 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.print("Found SGP30 serial #");
  Serial.print(sgp.serialnumber[0], HEX);
  Serial.print(sgp.serialnumber[1], HEX);
  Serial.println(sgp.serialnumber[2], HEX);

  // If you have a baseline measurement from before you can assign it to start, to 'self-calibrate'
  //sgp.setIAQBaseline(0x8E68, 0x8F41);  // Will vary for each sensor!
}

int counter = 0;
void loop() {
  // If you have a temperature / humidity sensor, you can set the absolute humidity to enable the humditiy compensation for the air quality signals
  sgp.setHumidity(getAbsoluteHumidity(t, h));

  if (! sgp.IAQmeasure()) {
    Serial.println("Measurement failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.print("TVOC "); Serial.print(sgp.TVOC); Serial.print(" ppb\t");
  Serial.print("eCO2 "); Serial.print(sgp.eCO2); Serial.println(" ppm");

  if (! sgp.IAQmeasureRaw()) {
    Serial.println("Raw Measurement failed");
    return;
  }
 
  counter++;
  if (counter == 20) {
    counter = 0;

    uint16_t TVOC_base, eCO2_base;
    if (! sgp.getIAQBaseline(&eCO2_base, &TVOC_base)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to get baseline readings");
      return;
    }
    Serial.print("****Baseline values: eCO2: 0x"); Serial.print(eCO2_base, HEX);
    Serial.print(" & TVOC: 0x"); Serial.println(TVOC_base, HEX);
  }


      h = bme.readHumidity();
      t = (bme.readTemperature()-2);
      dp = t-0.36*(100.0-h);
    
      p = bme.readPressure()/100.0F;
      pin = 0.02953*p;
      dtostrf(t, 5, 1, temperatureFString);
      dtostrf(h, 5, 1, humidityString);
      dtostrf(p, 6, 1, pressureString);
      dtostrf(pin, 5, 2, pressureInchString);
      dtostrf(dp, 5, 1, dpString);
 
      Serial.print("Temperature = ");
      Serial.println(temperatureFString);
      Serial.print("Humidity = ");
      Serial.println(humidityString);
      Serial.print("Pressure = ");
      Serial.println(pressureString); 

if(Serial.find(0x42)){    //start to read when detect 0x42
    Serial.readBytes(buf,LENG);
 
    if(buf[0] == 0x4d){
      if(checkValue(buf,LENG)){
        PM01Value=transmitPM01(buf); //count PM1.0 value of the air detector module
        PM2_5Value=transmitPM2_5(buf);//count PM2.5 value of the air detector module
        PM10Value=transmitPM10(buf); //count PM10 value of the air detector module 
      }           
    } 
  }

    static unsigned long OledTimer=millis();  
    if (millis() - OledTimer >=1000) 
    {
     OledTimer=millis(); 
    }
      
      Serial.print("PM1.0: ");  
      Serial.print(PM01Value);
      Serial.println("  ug/m3");            
    
      Serial.print("PM2.5: ");  
      Serial.print(PM2_5Value);
      Serial.println("  ug/m3");     
      
      Serial.print("PM10 : ");  
      Serial.print(PM10Value);
      Serial.println("  ug/m3");   
      Serial.println();
      
      Serial.println("...............................................");

        if (client.connect(server,80))  // "184.106.153.149" or api.thingspeak.com
    {
        String postStr = apiKey;
        postStr +="&field1=";
        postStr += String(temperatureFString);
        postStr +="&field2=";
        postStr += String(humidityString);
        postStr +="&field3=";
        postStr += String(pressureString);
        postStr +="&field4=";
        postStr += String(PM01Value);
        postStr +="&field5=";
        postStr += String(PM2_5Value);
        postStr +="&field6=";
        postStr += String(PM10Value);
        postStr +="&field7=";
        postStr += String(sgp.eCO2);
        postStr +="&field8=";
        postStr += String(sgp.TVOC);
        postStr += "\r\n\r\n";
        
        client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
        client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
        client.print("Connection: close\n");
        client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: "+apiKey+"\n");
        client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
        client.print("Content-Length: ");
        client.print(postStr.length());
        client.print("\n\n");
        client.print(postStr); 
    }   
    delay(16000);
    client.stop();  
}
```

Comment: It would help quite a bit if you would edit the question to include the output of the serial port around the time it stops. Change the Serial speed to 115200 so that it will properly show crash-related output from the ESP32.

Comment: Add more logging to narrow down the failure.  Staring at code, looking for problems, is not very effective.

Comment: I have had a simillar issue in the past. It was due to brownout detector and flimsy power supply. You can disable brownout detector and see will that make a difference.

Comment: What is a brownout detector and how do I disable it?

Comment: Brown out occurs when the device draws too much current and causes the power supply to sag. This is known to occur in some ESP32 boards when using a 5v supply which goes through their 5 to 3.3 volt converter and you are transmitting via WiFi  There should be a console message if that happens. That's another reason to make note if your console messages. What library are you using, Arduino or ESP-IDF?

Comment: I know way too little about this haha. The problem is that on my USB port the ESP32 seems to work much better so its much harder to get the "brown out" (if that is the reason). It indeed occurs way faster using a external 5V powersupply. Should I use a high V powersupply then? Also how do I check the library

Comment: The ESP32 board probably accepts 3.3v or 5v only (read your hardware documentation!). The ESP32 circuit is natively 3.3v. If you supply 5v the onboard converter is used. It would ls be best to supply a well regulated 3.3v. Just make sure you connect it to the 3.3v pin. If the brownout isn't causing your problem, it could be a MIC error over wifi, which the ESP32 is also known to suffer. As requested before, provide a console monitor log!